# C recursive typedef structures

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following working code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Mystruct {
    int id;
    struct Mystruct** mystructures;
} Mystruct;

int main () {
    Mystruct* ms1 = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));
    ms1->id = 1;

    Mystruct* ms2 = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));
    ms2->id = 2;

    Mystruct* ms3 = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));
    ms3->id = 3;

    ms1->mystructures = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct) * 2);
    ms1->mystructures[0] = (struct Mystruct*)ms2;
    ms1->mystructures[1] = (struct Mystruct*)ms3;

    printf("%d\n", ms1->mystructures[0]->id);
}
```

I don't like having to use both `Mystruct` and `(struct Mystruct)` to refer to the same data type. Is there a way to use typedefined Mystruct recursively like in

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    Mystruct** mystructures;
} Mystruct;
```

? This doesn't compile. Thanks

Comment: I do not like Marmite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmite either. So not really a problem

Comment: Well, I was about to post an answer when this was marked as duplicate. Anyway, there's a bug in your code here: `ms1->mystructures = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct) * 2);`. `mystructures` is of type `Mystruct **`, so you need to allocate space for `Mystruct *`. It should be `malloc(sizeof(Mystruct *) * 2);`.

Comment: To avoid this kind of mistakes, I usually prefer (and recommend) to use `sizeof(*X)` when allocating space for `X`, this makes sure you always allocate the correct amount. So in this case you'd do `malloc(sizeof(*ms1->mystructures) * 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define your typedef and then the struct:

```
typedef struct Mystruct Mystruct;

struct Mystruct {
    int id;
    Mystruct** mystructures;
} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You MUST use "struct Mystruct" only when defining the struct. Once you typedef it to "Mystruct" you can use "Mystruct" anywhere you want.